# Half-screen image with Gatsby StaticImage

Tags: css, reactjs, gatsby, gatsby-image, gatsby-plugin

I am working on a website made with Gatsby v. 4. On static pages the template expects a background image that takes up slightly less than half the screen. All background images are loaded via the `StaticImage` component of Gatsby's '[gatsby-plugin-image](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-plugin-image/)' plugin.

Is there a way to get this background image by using the `height` and `width` (or other) attributes of Gatsby's StaticImage component?

I am currently achieving this through an external `.scss` style sheet in this way:

```
  img {  
    height: calc(50vh);
    width: calc(300vh);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have exposed an `style` or `imgStyle` `props` in both: `StaticImage` as well as `GatsbyImage`.

- `style`: Inline styles applied to the outer wrapper.
- `imgStyle`: Inline styles applied to the `<img>` element.

*Source: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-plugin-image/#shared-props*

Depending on how's your JSX structure you may want to use one or another but answering your question: yes, there's no need of using an external `.scss` file, you can use inline styles as desired:

```
<StaticImage
  imgStyle={{ width:"300vh", height:"50vh" }}
  style={{ width:"300vh", height:"50vh" }}
/>
```

Use whichever works better for your scenario.